# Does groovy respect final variables defined outside a closure or anonymous class?

Tags: groovy, scope, closures, final

Today I found some corious behaviour of groovy while porting some java code to groovy.

Something that we do all the time in java: build anonymous classes in a loop (e.g. for actions) and reference final variables that are declared outside of this class.

If you let run this code in groovy, you get surprisingly not 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, but instead you will get 9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9. This means groovy does not bind the respective final variable i to each anonymous class, but just uses the last set value on exectution.

I can not find any reason for this behaviour in the groovy documentation. By the way, I get the same behaviour, if I use a groovy closure instead of an anonymous class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] list = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        list[i] = i;
    }
    Runnable[] runnables = new Runnable[10];
    for (final int i : list) {
        runnables[i] = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        };
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        runnables[i].run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Odd... I'll investigate to see if this is known behaviour

In the mean time, you can work around it by declaring another variable inside the loop generating runnables, then use this in your Runnable:

```
for (int i : list) {
    int k = i
    runnables[i] = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(k);
        }
    }
}
```

Or by generating the Runnable array using `collect`:

```
Runnable[] runnables = list.collect { i -> 
    new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println( i );
        }
    }
}
```

#### Edit

I've asked around, and outside of class properties, `final` is currently ignored by Groovy. It's something that could be added in the future though

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with the `for` loop. Simplifying the code:

```
def runnables = []
for (int i: 0..9) {
    runnables << {
        println i
    }
}
runnables*.call() // prints 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9
```

Interestingly, a traditional `for` loop outputs all 10s:

```
def runnables = []
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    runnables << {
        println i
    }
}
runnables*.call() // prints 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10
```

Using a range in place of the `for` loop will work as intended:

```
def runnables = []
(0..9).each { i ->
    runnables << {
        println i
    }
}
runnables*.call() // prints 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

So yes, the closure (or anonymous Runnable), when called, looks up the reference to `i` from within the scope of the already-executed `for` loop, at which point the value of `i` is at its fully incremented value. I'm not sure if this is intentional or not.